# Python: Expected an indented block

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

I thought everything was properly indented here but I am getting an **IndentationError: expected an indented block** at the **else:** statement.  Am I making an obvious mistake here?

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    new_string = ""
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for letter in text:
       for vowel in vowels:
           if (lower(letter) == vowel):
               #do nothing
           else:
               #append letter to the new string
               new_string += letter
    return new_string
```

Comment: For empty blocks you should use `pass`.

Comment: In case you already knew that you had to put something in the `if` block and thought that you had… a comment isn't a statement. It's simplest to think of it as if comments get removed before the code gets parsed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Do nothing* translates to using the `pass` keyword to fill an otherwise empty block (which is not allowed). See the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) for more information.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    new_string = ""
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for letter in text:
       for vowel in vowels:
           if (lower(letter) == vowel):
               #do nothing
               pass
           else:
               #append letter to the new string
               new_string += letter
    return new_string
```

Comment: Nice tutorial link for further explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You need to put something inside the `if` block.  If you don't want to do anything, put `pass`.

Alternatively, just reverse your condition so you only have one block:

```
if lower(letter) != vowel:
    new_string += letter
```

Incidentally, I don't think your code will do what you intend it to do, but that's an issue for another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

```
if (lower(letter) == vowel):
    #do nothing
```

Try:

```
if (lower(letter) == vowel):
    #do nothing
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be caused by mixing tabs and spaces. However, this is probably caused by having nothing inside your if statement. You can use "pass" as a placeholder (see example below).

```
    if condition:
        pass
```

Information on pass: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/pass.html

Comment: To be fair, there are no tabs in the example. +1 for `pass`, though.

Comment: Yeh, I jumped the gun a bit, I've amended my answer accordingly :)