# How to fix "IndentationError: expected an indented block" in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

I am trying to do a API test on a URL with Python, I have the following code block

```
       def simple_get(url):
        try:
            page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
            if page_response.status_code == 200:
            # extract
            else:
                print(page_response.status_code)
                # notify, try again
        except requests.Timeout as e:
            print("It is time to timeout")
            print(str(e))
        except # other exception
```

When I run it give me the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-16-6291efcb97a0>", line 11
else:
   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I dont understand why is the notebook still asking for indentation when I already have the "else" statement indented

Comment: make sure that you are not mixing tabs with spaces and use 4-spaces indentation, as per python standard

Comment: There needs to be a statement after the `if ...:` You can just put in a `pass`

Comment: because you haven't told the if to pass.

Comment: why am I getting negative points

Comment: probably because it's a question about basic debugging

Comment: It's an ok question. Maybe try to interpret the error message more carefully. I interpret it as "Line 11 else is excepted to be indented.. why? ... ~thinking , thinking..~ oh, line 10 if doesn't have any task to perform "

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764912/python-expected-an-indented-block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Expected an indented block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764912/python-expected-an-indented-block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you did not tell the program what to do when the first condition is satisfied (if statement). If you are not sure about what to do in if, you can use python build in 'pass'.

```
if page_response.status_code == 200:
    pass
else:
    print(page_response.status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, moving on to the next exception

Comment: what's the next one @Jin?

Comment: I think this answer would be more valuable if you would write one or two sentence why this fixes the problem.

Comment: @syntonym Thanks

Comment: @syntonym, this fixed the problem because pass I did not set a condition for the if statement, therefore the "else" statement has indentation problem. After setting the pass condition, the "else" statement no longer has indentation problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic concept in `Python` to start coding:
Lines which start with `#` are ignored within a code block.

The code here

```
    if page_response.status_code == 200:
    # extract
    else:
        print(page_response.status_code)
```

literally translated as

```
    if page_response.status_code == 200:
    else:
        print(page_response.status_code)
```

and therefore produces `IndentationError`.

You can solve it by placing at least `pass` command or any working line into to the `if` statement.

Similar question is already asked before:
[Python: Expected an indented block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764912/python-expected-an-indented-block)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def simple_get(url):
    try:
        page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        if page_response.status_code == 200:
            print(page_response.status_code)
            pass
            # extract
        else:
            print(page_response.status_code)
            # notify, try again
    except requests.Timeout as e:

        print("It is time to timeout")
        print(str(e))
simple_get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
```